# n indistinguishable balls into k distinguishable bins

Tags: combinatorics

my math teacher wrote a problem today:

In how many ways can you put 9 similar balls into 3 bins stacked on top of each other, so that the top bin will have at least 4 balls.

His answer was: let's put 4 balls into the top bin. then we're left with 5 balls into 3 bins, without order being important, and repetition (putting into the same bin) is allowed. Therefore the answer is $5+3-1 \choose 3-1$ = $7 \choose 2$ = 21

What I don't understand is why is it  $5+3-1 \choose 3-1$ and not  $5+3-1 \choose 3$? we're choosing 3 bins, not 2.

Comment: I am confused: Don't you have $4$ bins in the first sentence?

Comment: @zoli There are 3 bins, the top bin have at least 4 balls

Comment: Is there any problem with my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. So we have three bins and five balls. (We can forget about the first four balls in the top bin.)

So the question is: How many ways there are to arrange five indistinguishable balls in three distinguishable bins?

The answer is

$$\binom{7}{2},$$

because we have $5+2$ abstract objects ($2$ walls between bins and  $5$ balls) and we have to select two of the $7$ objects to play the role of the walls.

So, to answer your question explicitly: **Three bins are separated by $2$ (and not $3$) walls [floors]. $\color{red}{\text{That is, we are choosing two separators and not three bins.}}$**